# .htaccess rewrite for php logic

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building an FAQ section. It will have separate sections

SECTION1
  Q1
  A1

Q2
  A2

SECTION2
...ETC.

I am trying to add some PHP logic that will work with .htaccess rewrite.

The page will have the following logic:

```
$faq_S = $_GET['section'];
$faq_Q = $_GET['q'];    

if (!isset($faq_C)) { 
  // show all sections
} else {
  // show only the section that's set

  if (!isset($faq_q)) { 
     // open the question
  } else {
     // show all questions in the section
  }
}
```

So, in order to be able to access the page without section and question values I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^faq|faq/$ pages/faq.inc.php [NC,L]
```

and I was hoping to add section and question as:

```
RewriteRule ^faq/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ pages/faq.inc.php?cat=$1&q=$2 [NC,L]
```

But it seems that while the first rule works, the second does not. Also I think there might be a better way to have it combined in one. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `ReWriteRule` in your`.htaccess` file to direct `/faq`, `/faq/value1`, and `/faq/value1/value2` to the requested page setting `cat` and `q`

```
ReWriteRule ^faq/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$ pages/faq.inc.php?cat=$1&q=$2
```

Ofcourse, you could change `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to any other selector you like...

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, this takes the place of BOTH of your current rules

Comment: It will redirect to: `mydomain.com/pages/faq.inc.php?cat=&q=`. `$_GET['cat']` and `$_GET['q']` will both be empty variables (e.g. `$_GET['cat'] == ''`)

Comment: This is great. What will happen is some one just uses: http://mydomain.com/faq ?  I tried the links in the format (above) and I could not get it to work. I've added "_" too.

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try again. Maybe I missed something

Comment: My bad, I was checking is vars were available instead if they had value. Thanks, works great.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the variables would always be sent in the answer... Good to hear you got it working!